# Errors when compiling Boost ASIO examples

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I have been struggling for hours trying to get this example from the official boost homepage to run:

```
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::co_spawn;
using boost::asio::detached;
using boost::asio::use_awaitable;
namespace this_coro = boost::asio::this_coro;

awaitable<void> echo(tcp::socket socket)
{
  try
  {
    char data[1024];
    for (;;)
    {
      std::size_t n = co_await socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), use_awaitable);
      co_await async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data, n), use_awaitable);
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::printf("echo Exception: %s\n", e.what());
  }
}

awaitable<void> listener()
{
  auto executor = co_await this_coro::executor;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(executor, {tcp::v4(), 55555});
  for (;;)
  {
    tcp::socket socket = co_await acceptor.async_accept(use_awaitable);
    co_spawn(executor,
        [socket = std::move(socket)]() mutable
        {
          return echo(std::move(socket));
        },
        detached);
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context(1);

    boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto){ io_context.stop(); });

    co_spawn(io_context, listener, detached);

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::printf("Exception: %s\n", e.what());
  }
}
```

I'm on Linux and saved the source to `/usr/local/boost_1_70_0`. I read in the documentation that I had to include `<boost/system/error_code>` and `<boost/system/system_error>` (Why wasn't this in the code example?). After much reading here at StackOverflow, I figured out I should also use `-lboost_system`, but then the compiler just complained that it couldn't find it. Another tip was to use `-lpthread`, and now it stopped complaining about. The last command I tried was 
`g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_70_0  main.cpp -lpthread`
 However, it says:

```
error: ‘boost::asio::awaitable’ has not been declared
 using boost::asio::awaitable;
                    ^~~~~~~
```

Is this a bug in the code? It's extremely difficult for someone who have no experience using these libraries to get going when there are so many pitfalls. I can see that there are many others struggling with this, none of the answers seems to help in my case. Am I just stupid, or is there something wrong with the example? I am sorry for the long post, and I am forever grateful if someone could give me a hand, because I've struggled for many hours with this.

Comment: To compile this code, your compiler should support [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), but unfortunately g++ doesn't handle it yet. You could try to compile this on MSVC.

Comment: It says in the official boost documentation to compile using "c++ ...". Doesn't that invoke gcc? Because I tried that as well.

Comment: I read somewhere that these are extensions by Microsoft to the c++ language, and that this is the reason why gcc doesn't support it. I hope they don't use non-supported extensions in the boost examples. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: I can easily compile this code with Visual C++ compiler version 19.20 with [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support?view=vs-2019) flag enabled and boost 1.70. As I said, currently coroutines (as part c++20) are supported only by CLang and MSVC compilers. You can wait until g++ supports this, or use other compilers.

Comment: I didn't know they were part of c++20. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem to compile on Windows and Mac and took me hours to solve it, so as reference for others to compile on Visual Studio and CMake add:

on the command arguments editbox of Manage Configurations

> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="/await /EHsc"

for Mac I set directly the variable on the cmake file:

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines-ts")

With gcc it seems that the flag to use is "-fcoroutines"

It may be useful as reference the full cmake file:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for TGFLocalClient, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Boost section

# set(Boost_DEBUG "ON")
set(Boost_LIB_PREFIX "lib")
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Users/Andrea/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0")
set(BOOST_LIBRARIES "date_time" "regex")


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})

message(STATUS "${BOOST_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "${BOOST_FOUND}")            
message(STATUS "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")     
message(STATUS "${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")     
message(STATUS "${BOOST_LIBRARIES}")        
message("${Boost_regex_FOUND}")
message("${Boost_regex_LIBRARY}")

include_directories("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (TGFLocalClient "TGFLocalClient.cpp" "TGFLocalClient.h" "ServiceDiscovery.h" "NetProtocol.h")

target_link_libraries(TGFLocalClient Boost::date_time Boost::regex)

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```